# Using Two loops to Transverse a 2D Array in a Down and to the Right Direction

Tags: arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to build a set of for loops to transverse a 2D array completely once in a down and to the right direction only (south-east if your thinking of it like a map direction) . I can not seem to get the variables and conditions right in my for loops to make a down and to the right search correct without running into a out of bounds error or running to short. Here is what I have so far. I've built a set for every other direction but for some reason I cannot find the correct set of variables and conditions to set my for loops with to get a down and to the right transverse.

```
    for(int k = dimention-1; k >= 0; k--){
        for(int j = dimention; j<= dimention+dimention ;j++){
            int i = k - j;
            System.out.print(testArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    for(int k = 1; k <= dimention-1; k++){
        for(int j = dimention-1; j>=k;j--){
            int i = j - k;
            System.out.print(testArray[j][i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here is the break down. You can un-comment the print lines to get a break down. Of how the pattern works. Please note that dimention is the dimention of the matrix.

```
    //top left to bottom right searching SE
    System.out.println("SE Direction!");

    for(int k = 0; k <= dimention-1; k++){
        //System.out.print("k = " + k + ", ");
        for(int j = 0; j<=k;j++){
            int i = j - k;
            //System.out.print("j = " + j + ", ");
            //System.out.print("i = " + i + ", ");
            System.out.print(testArray[dimention - 1 + i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    for (int k = dimention -2; k >=0; k--){
        //System.out.print("k = " + k + ", ");
        for(int j = 0; j <=k;j++){
            int i = j - k;
            //System.out.print("j = " + j + ", ");
            //System.out.print("i = " + i + ", | ");
            System.out.print(testArray[j][dimention-1+i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```